# Filtering objects by year AND month of creation date

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have problem with filtering objects.
Code which works properly on local machine, doesn't work on server.

Here is the use case:
I have multiple objects in database table created in July 2014.
I need to count all objects created in this month and year, so I am doing this:

```
number = Payment.objects.filter(time_created__year=year_created, time_created__month=month_created).count()+1
```

Unfortunately, it always returns 1, because filtering doesn't work, it cannot find objects created in July.

When I try to select objects using shell:

```
Payment.objects.filter(time_created__year=2014, time_created__month=8)
```

returns `[]` (no results). I've tried:

```
Payment.objects.filter(time_created__year=2014)
```

returns multiple objects. So I wanted to select first object:

```
a = Payment.objects.filter(time_created__year=2014)[0]
```

And tried to display its month:

```
a.time_created.month
```

I was VERY surprised, because it returned `8`

**Do you have any idea, why I am not able to filter objects using month?** And again, it works properly on local machine with windows, but its not on production hosting with linux.

Comment: My guess is that is has something to do with localization, I think they differ on both machines. Also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I though so, but the code above should work on linux machine, and it doesn't. Why the `time_created.month` of a single objects returns 8, and when I tried to filter using this number I get 0 results?

Comment: Do you get results when you filter _only_ by month ?

Comment: do you use the same backend for both your local dev environment and the prouction server?

Comment: I get nothing when I filter by month only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using Django version 1.6.0 or above, in which USE_TZ = True is default value in its settings file, and when you try to check query on django toolbar it will look something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM `app_payment` WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`app_ayment`.`time_created`, 'UTC', 'Asia/Kolkata')) = 8);
```

which return Empty set.

So either **install pytz** and **load the time zone tables with mysql_tzinfo_to_sql**.

```
pip install pytz
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u -p mysql
```

or simply comment line **USE_TZ = True** in your settings file.